# is there a ui-bootstrap port to bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using angularjs and bootstrap 3.0
I would like to use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
but I saw that it is using bootstrap version 2.3

Does anyone know of a port of this library to version 3.0 of bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is coming, patience :)

More info here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/331

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use the tool **[bootply](http://bootply.com/new)**

How to use,

copy your html code to the HTML part  and click on the `2.x > 3` button, it will convert the copy code to bootstrap 3